# I block ssh access for root. How do I add a banner or message so that users using root ssh will know not to use it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I remove root ssh access. Is there a way to show a banner to attempts for root access?

Right now they are seeing permission denied.

### What I tried

I tried to use `/etc/issue.net` and `Banner /etc/issue.net` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and this will be shown to all users regardless.

Is this the simplest solution?

Is it okay to show "You cannot use root for ssh access. Please use alice" instead? where alice is an actual user account

I am using ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Match` block:

```
Banner /etc/issue.everyone

Match User root
    Banner /etc/issue.root
```

Note that Match blocks must go *after* all regular (non-Match) settings. There is also a limited amount of settings that can be used within Match (e.g. no parameters that are needed before the username is even known); fortunately banners are shown after the client sends the username.

Comment: Are you sure this is right and a good idea. It seems to me it would require the root user to have a valid login - albeit one that can chuck the user straight out (which could still allow sftp/scp work-arounds)

Comment: This may not work. According to the [manual](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Banner), the banner is sent before authentication. So the ssh server doesn't yet know that the client will be authenticating as root.

Comment: @Kenster: Most clients will try null authentication (using method `none`) before any other methods – the userauth request packet will still include the username (regardless of auth method), and the server will respond with the banner message before returning failure. (The failure message is also how the client learns what methods are available, so it's possible to vary auth methods by username as well.) So it's true that the banner is shown before any _real_ auth attempts, but it's still shown in response to the client sending the username thanks to the invisible null-auth attempt.

Comment: @davidgo: `Banner` is a pre-login banner, it's not the regular motd.

Comment: This works for me after I tested thank you